# Is there a SQL equivalent of Gremlin query to find all incoming edges of a vertex?

Tags: sql, gremlin, graph-databases

Is there a SQL equivalent of below Gremlin query to find all incoming edges of a vertex? Is it possible to traverse graph using SQL query?

Gremlin query:

`g.V().hasLabel("VertexLabel").inE().hasLabel("EdgeLabel")`

Properties of Node with "VertexLabel" does not contain any edge related information.

Comment: To fully answer this question requires additional information. Which database are you using, or planning to use? What will the data model of your database schema be? It would also help to see what you have tried so far.